# Rails4: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

I'm hosting a rails 4 application with phusion passenger on a apache server and I'm getting a 500 error when I try to access my password protected admin pages.

Looking at the log I see I'm getting an "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error."

I have looked on the web and SO, it seems this is usually coming from a badly configured .htaccess. The problem is my application is using **http_basic_authenticate_with** so I am unsure how to correct the problem.

Here is my admin_controller.rb with the authentification:

```rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController

    @config_name = CONFIG["name"]
    @config_password = CONFIG["password"]

    http_basic_authenticate_with :name => @config_name, 
        :password => @config_password, 
        :realm => (I18n.t "msg_authentication")
```

Here is my routes.rb (I don't think the error comes from here):

```rb
LandingPage::Application.routes.draw do

    get "admin/gestion"
    get "admin/download"
    get "admin/email"
    get "admin/show"
    get "admin/new"
    get "admin/validate"

    get "admin", to: "admin#home"

    root 'main#home'

    resources :mail_infos, controller: :main, :path => "/"
    resources :mail_bodies, controller: :admin, :path => "/admin"

end
```

My virtual host code:

```
PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/wrappers/ruby

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName DOMAIN.com
    DocumentRoot /var/landing-page/public
    <Directory /var/landing-page/public>
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
    RewriteEngine off
    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/landing-page.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #        LogLevel warn 

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my log for apache rendering the application:

```
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [error] [client 98.14.198.144] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3063): [client 98.14.198.144] r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] core.c(3069): [client 98.14.198.144] redirected from r->uri = /admin
[Wed Mar 19 13:44:51 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 98.14.198.144] Zlib: Compressed 632 to 387 : URL /index.php
```

Rails probably makes something similar to an .htaccess with http_basic_authenticate_with. So if I could get how to modify the http_basic_authenticate_with like people usually modify the .htaccess that would be great, thanks.

**EDIT:** As suspected by Chuanpin Zhu, the issue doesn't seem to actually do with the http_basic_authenticate_with method. I've commented it out and it still had an issue. As a matter of fact if I try to go to:

DOMAIN.com/none-existing-page

I still get the 500 serveur error and the **"redirected from r->uri = /index.php"** message. When in all logic I should get a 404 error.

If I comment out the "root" command in routes.rb DOMAIN.com gives a 404 error, yet DOMAIN.com/none-existing-page still gives out a 500 apache error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from an .htaccess in /var/ which affected my site in /var/landing-page.

Answer (score 0):

you might have a recursive redirect_to method. Looking though the log,

```
redirected from r->uri = /index.php
```

this redirected_to shows more than 10 times, so please check your related controllers, or post it.

Comment: Any idea where this comes from? My application_controller.rb is empty and even DOMAIN.com/none-existing-page gives a 500 error instead of 404.

I don't have any index.php in my app. Though my Apache serveur also hosts a few wordpress and other projects which might host php pages, I don't understand on what level it could intefere and how to find out.